# Remove first and last line from file?

Tags: ant

I have a file that has lines like this.

```
(function($, _) {

.....


})(jQuery, jQuery.ZOF);
```

now I want to remove the first and last line of the file and then concat this file to another file , How could it be possible with ant?

Answer (score 2):

`loadfile` can be used as follows:

```
    <loadfile srcfile="test.xml" property="file.first.and.last.line.removed">
      <filterchain>
        <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.HeadFilter">
          <param name="lines" value="-1"/>
          <param name="skip" value="1"/>
        </filterreader>
        <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.TailFilter">
          <param name="lines" value="-1"/>
          <param name="skip" value="1"/>
        </filterreader>
      </filterchain>
    </loadfile>

    <echo message="${file.first.and.last.line.removed}" file="output.txt" append="true" />
```

First we use a `HeadFilter` to read everything but skipping the first line, then we "tail" the result with a `TailFilter` skipping the last line.

The last line appends the content to another file.